# Java StringTokenizer - delim format

Tags: java

Where I can get *StringTokenizer* *delim* format?

For example I had this string:

```
tokens = new StringTokenizer(s.nextLine(), "-|\\+|/|\\*", true);
```

After few attempts I add `\\` and expression start works, but I don't know why I should escape this symbols, in the StringTokenizer reference no info about that.

Comment: Your string tokenizer delimiters are `-`, `|`, `/`, `\ ` , `+` and `*`. Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: No, I need only: `( ) + - * /` for calculator, but I don't now how to format *delim* string.

Comment: You are not supposed to format it. The delimiters are just the characters in it. It doesn't have a format. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) says: "All characters in the `delim` argument are the delimiters for separating tokens".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the '\' character is a consequence of using it in *any* String (or even `char`).  It doesn't have anything to do with `StringTokenizer.`  That is why you see nothing about escaping back-slash ('\').

```
String x = "Windows likes using '\\' in path info.";
System.out.println(x);
```

Gives

```
Windows likes using '\' in path info.
```

Similarly

```
char c = '\\';
System.out.println("c = " + c);
```

Gives

```
c = \
```

So the fact that you are giving '\' as a delimiter to the String argument of StringTokenizer forces you to escape it with an extra back-slash.